# How can I disable grey color of code inside #ifdef in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

As you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c9Dl.jpg), some code (it is `int aaa = 1`) inside `#ifdef` (a preprocessor block) is grey. It is inconvenient to read when there is a lot of similar code. Is there a way to remove the grey color on it and makes it same color like `int aaa = 0` in the image?

The output in image is for C++ code. I append the code here in case the pic cannot be shown:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG    
    int aaa = 0    
#else    
    int aaa = 1    
#endif
```

I had tried some configurations in `workbench.colorCustomizations`, but didn't find the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `C_Cpp.dimInactiveRegions`. You can put that in a settings.json file like this:

```json
"C_Cpp.dimInactiveRegions": false
```

The setting's description:

> Controls whether inactive preprocessor blocks are colored differently than active code. This setting has no effect if IntelliSense is disabled or if using the Default High Contrast theme.

There are also the following related settings you might want to play with: `C_Cpp.inactiveRegionOpacity`, `C_Cpp.inactiveRegionForegroundColor`, and `C_Cpp.inactiveRegionBackgroundColor`.