VS Code syntax highlighting for disabled C++ code
I'm trying to build a color theme for VS Code, specifically for C/C++. Works fine, but I cannot write a textmate rule for disabled code. When I used Qt Creator, it had a specific style for disabled code:

You can see the syntax highlighting understands that this code is disabled (or rather, the clangd tells the QTC that this code is disabled) and it applies an appropriate style for this section. Some styles slip through though, like a comment in italic, but I don't care since the color is my main concern.
When I tried to style disabled code in VS Code, I could not find a textmate scope for it. The Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes just tells me it's some code, it even tries to highlight some of its portions:

But the text is slightly faded than the rest of the code, so it somehow understands that it's disabled, but there's no textmate scope for it. How do I style it then? I would like it to be like in QTC, all one color. I tried using this extension, but it didn't add any textmate scopes. I have official C/C++ extensions installed, and I use clangd instead of IntelliSense, in case it matters.
Update: This seems to be very related. If I understood this comment right, there's now two options: background highlighting (just changes color a bit, but no control how exactly it does that) and opacity (text has some opacity and therefore fades, as I've mentioned above).
Update 2: Ackshually, there's some control over clangd's background option: it lets you change color, but this setting is hidden and only accessible as a workbench color customization: "clangd.inactiveRegions.background": "#ff0000".

I don't know if VS Code supports the same #pragmas as Visual Studio editor, but you may try. In VS a section of code between #pragma region name  and #pragma endregion comment is collapsible. I always mark this way my autogenerated code.

For clangd, there's the clangd.inactiveRegions.background colour customization point.
For cpptools, the following settings are available. Example settings.json:
"C_Cpp.inactiveRegionForegroundColor": "#ff0000",
"C_Cpp.inactiveRegionBackgroundColor": "#00ff00",
"C_Cpp.inactiveRegionOpacity": 0.55,

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#color-formats.

I also mention this in my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/75319710/11107541, but technically these are different questions, so I won't dup-close.

Nah, the description says: This setting only applies when inactive region dimming is enabled. And the C_Cpp: Dim Inactive Regions description says This setting has no effect if IntelliSense is disabled... I mentioned that I use clangd, which is a replacement for IntelliSense. I tried putting these in settings.json as workbench color customizations, no effect.

clangd actually supports something similar, but this replaces opacity mode. "clangd.inactiveRegions.background": "#ff0000" will make a different background, but text color (foreground) won't change. And opacity setting won't help here, since it's disabled if background is used (sadly you can't have both).

The fade out is controlled by extension providing the Unnecessary DiagnosticTag during diagnostics

example, "editorUnnecessaryCode.opacity": "#000000c0" will render the code with 75% opacity


Doesn't work for me. Are you sure this is compatible with clangd?
